# ios: i want to add border at top and bottom side in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, layer

> i have applied below code in viewdidload() but using this code border is arrive but it scrolling with table content.i want fix border at top and bottom side.
>
> here my code is ->

```
    let topBorder = CAShapeLayer()
    let topPath = UIBezierPath()
    topPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    topPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tblFilter.frame.width, y: 0))
    topBorder.path = topPath.cgPath
    topBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    topBorder.lineWidth = 1.0
    topBorder.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    tblFilter.layer.addSublayer(topBorder)

    let bottomBorder = CAShapeLayer()
    let bottomPath = UIBezierPath()
    bottomPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: tblFilter.frame.height))
    bottomPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tblFilter.frame.width, y: tblFilter.frame.height))
    bottomBorder.path = bottomPath.cgPath
    bottomBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    bottomBorder.lineWidth = 1.0
    bottomBorder.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    tblFilter.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
```

> give me suggetion and thanks

Comment: It is not clear from your code where the layer is being added. The math for your `CGPoints` is also incorrect, as the layer will be added out of bounds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using below methods to add borders to any view. Please take a look if it helps you.

```
//MARK: - Add Border to View -
func addTopBorderWithColor(_ objView : UIView, color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
let border = CALayer()
border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: objView.frame.size.width, height: width)
objView.layer.addSublayer(border)
}

func addBottomBorderWithColor(_ objView : UIView, color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
let border = CALayer()
border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: objView.frame.size.height - width, width: objView.frame.size.width, height: width)
objView.layer.addSublayer(border)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a method which uses few enums to achieve what you want to do. Please see `objective c`  code below

```
-(void) addUIViewAt:(postionOfView) position OfView:(UIView *) view ofHeight:(int) height ofBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor{
UIView *viewForBorder = [[UIView alloc] init] ;
if (position == positionTop){
    [viewForBorder setFrame:CGRectMake(view.bounds.origin.x
                                       , view.bounds.origin.y, view.bounds.size.width, height)];
}
else if (position == positionBottom){
    [viewForBorder setFrame:CGRectMake(view.bounds.origin.x
                                       , view.bounds.size.height - height, view.bounds.size.width, height)];
}
else if (position == positionLeft){
    [viewForBorder setFrame:CGRectMake(view.bounds.origin.x
                                       , view.bounds.origin.y, height, view.bounds.size.height)];
}
else{
    [viewForBorder setFrame:CGRectMake(view.bounds.size.width - height
                                       , view.bounds.origin.y, height, view.bounds.size.height)];
}
[viewForBorder setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
[view addSubview:viewForBorder];
//    viewForBorder.layer.zPosition = MAXFLOAT;
}
```

Also use these enums for the method above

```
/**
this used to detect the position of border overlay on a view
*/
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
positionTop,
positionRight,
positionLeft,
positionBottom,
} postionOfView;
```

Just feed this method with appropriate values